# Creating columns and moving cards between them with the API

Tags: asana-api

is it possible with the current API to create columns (the new "Boards" feature), create cards in a specific column, or move cards between columns?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we plan to deploy these feature, the Boards API is still under development.

We are excited to hear that you are eager to use it.  If you’re interested in trying it out and helping to shape its implementation, please email us at devrel@asana.com. Note that we are still finalizing the design and some endpoints will change